# Error: Module name "cassandra-driver" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

Tags: node.js, cassandra, datastax-astra, datastax-node-driver

I am using datastax cassandra-driver to make a database.
This is connect-database:

```
import { require } from "./requirejs.mjs";
export async function run() {
   const { Client } = require("cassandra-driver");

const client1 = new Client({
  cloud: {
    get secureConnectBundle(){
       return "secure-connect-amazonfeud.zip"}
  },
  credentials: {
    get username(){
      return "<my username>"},
    get password(){
      return "<my password>"}
  },
});
await client1.connect();

const rs = await client1.execute("SELECT * FROM feud.users");
const results = await client1.execute("update feud.users set score=250 where id=1")
console.log(rs['rows'][0])
console.log(`Your cluster returned ${rs.rowLength} row(s)`);

await client1.shutdown();
}
```

This is main.js:

```
import { run } from "./connect-database.mjs";

run()
```

When I run connect-database.mjs, it works, but when I run main.js it gives me error "Uncaught Error Error: Module name "cassandra-driver" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
[https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded"](https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded%22)

When I change the format to be require[], it says "Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Client is not a constructor"

Please help

Comment: Can you show the content of your `requirejs.mjs` file?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a custom `require` in order to require `cassandra-driver`, you don't need to do that. `Client` function is exposed using `module.exports` in `cassandra-driver` so you can use a simple `import`.

An example that worked for me:

###### cassandraDriverTest.mjs

```
import { Client } from 'cassandra-driver';
import { inspect } from 'util';

const client = new Client({
  contactPoints: ['cp'],
  localDataCenter: 'dc1',
  keyspace: 'ks'
});

const query = '<query>';

client.execute(query)
  .then(result => console.log('User with email %s', result.rows[0].some_data,));
console.log(inspect(client));
```